# React Native Image element crashing with a URI location

Tags: image, uri, react-native

I'm trying to display an image with a URI location instead of a static image and it's not working.  I'm getting the red screen with the message:

> You are trying to render the global Image variable as a React element.
>   You probably forgot to require Image.

I simply took the default project (`react-native init awesomeProject`) and added this inside the View after the two Text elements:

```
<Image 
    style = {styles.base}
    source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
/>
```

and I enhanced the styles with an additional property:

```
base: {
    height: 400,
    width: 400 
},
```

I can't figure out why this wouldn't work as this is the simple example in the React Native docs.  Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to actually require the Image component:

```
var React = require("react-native");
var Image = React.Image;
```